# sumoselect multiple dropdownlist is flickring on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sumoselect.js

hi i was using [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) drop-down list with check boxes it is working fine on IE browser and with no flickering but on the chrome browser it is flickering when first time page loaded or refresh the page any one solve me figure out this problems.here i am attach the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.searchSelAll = $('.search-box-open-up').SumoSelect({ csvDispCount: 3, selectAll: true, search: true, searchText: 'Enter here.', up: false });
               });
</script>
<link href="css/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if not work use this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hideAll  {
        visibility:hidden;
     }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#mytab").removeClass("hideAll");
    });
</script>

<div id="mytab" class="hideAll">
 --Your Content here----
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   simply i have been put  set  display: none and call the j query show at the end of HTML DOM it will work for me.Here i am attach example.
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div id="div1" runat="server" class="col" style="display: none;">

      <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0; background-color: #FFF; border: 2px solid black;">

                <tr>
                    <td id="tdcompany1" runat="server">Select Company : </td>

                    <td id="tdcompany" runat="server" colspan="4">
                        <p data-tooltip data-tooltip-message="Please select company name to filter">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="370px" onchange="StartProgressBar();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="input-block-level">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </p>
                    </td>            </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.col').show(); // changed this line

            });
        </script>
```